# php jdate does not work properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array of dates as a MySQL query result. These dates are Gregorian and I have converted them to Persian with `jdate` function in `php` as below:

```
foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $value) 
{
        $val1 = strtotime($value->sub_date);
        $value->sub_date =jdate('y-m-d H:i',$val1);

        if (isset($value->unsub_date)) 
        {
                $val2 = strtotime($value->unsub_date);
                $value->unsub_date =jdate('y-m-d H:i',$val2);
        }

        $val3 = strtotime($value->first_sub);
        $value->first_sub =jdate('y-m-d H:i',$val3);

}
```

This code works fine but just the first element is not converted properly, The hour and second of first Persian date is incorrect but others are OK.

Comment: Try `var_dump( $value )` and make sure the first is the same format as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you try change your code and other case to the same..

```
    $val1 = strtotime($value->sub_date);
    $value->sub_date =jdate('y-m-d H:i',$val1);
```

To

```
    $value->sub_date = date('y-m-d H:i',strtotime($value->sub_date));
```

Comment: Example: 
$date = '25/05/2010';
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));